# How to read a file in javascript

Tags: javascript

the way how I wrote the path is it right?

```
 <script>
     fs = require('fs')
    fs.readFile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/qwe.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot read files on a computer from a webpage. Huge security risk

Comment: Do you know the difference between browser JavaScript and NodeJS? Or are you using Electron?

Comment: How do you know *there is something wrong*? Do you get an error message? If so, then why isn't that error message included in your question so we have that information? If not, then how **specifically** do you know *there is something wrong*? We can't see your screen from where we are, and as I've gotten older my mind reading skills have gotten weaker - I just can't quite reach halfway around the planet to read people's minds any more. It's your job to clearly describe the problem if you want our help; you've not done so yet.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I am new in this way no,I just need the simple code if the file reading

Comment: In the screen there is nothing but there is the text in text file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` object for this

```
var fileObj;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  fileObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
  fileObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


fileObj.open("GET", "file://abc.txt", false);
fileObj.onreadystatechange = function ()
{

    if(fileObj.readyState === 4 && (fileObj.status === 200 || fileObj.status == 0))
    {
        var fileText= fileObj.responseText;
        alert(fileText);
    }
}

fileObj.send(null);
```

Comment: I think this is gonna fail because of cross origin requests